# Rails format specifier differences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, http-headers

I'm about to lead a training seminar on REST for some coworkers, and I'd like to verify something regarding Rails routing.

Our app in its current form allows clients to specify format in three different ways:

1.

```
/path/to/resource.json
```

2.

```
/path/to/resource?format=json
```

3.

Accept header of the request

My question pertains to the first 2 options: is there any inherent difference in what these specifications do? Specifically, do they set only the Accept header, or the Content-Type header as well?

Comment: content type header!

Comment: Thanks, do you have any documentation to back that up? That's kind of what I'm most interested in.

Comment: yah wait I am providing details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `1` and `2` are not exactly different, since Rails typically generates routes like:

```
/something(.:format)
```

That means "there is an **optional** parameter `format` delimited with a dot". Parameters, however, can also be specified in **query string, which is not part of the route**.

So the second way of querying for JSON will make the route system think that the `format` is not in the route at all. When it comes to the controller, however, Rails will already have that query string parsed and will find the format when the time comes to respond.

That said, if you hit plain `/path/to/resource` without `format` specified anywhere, you'll get the same result as `2`: you hit a route assuming there's no format given. Still, Rails will parse the headers and determine the format it should respond with.

As for what the client needs to set: [accept header only](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html), `Content-Type` only makes sense when the user himself sends an entity, and it's only related to "how should Rails parse incoming parameters", it's not related to response. Of course, by default Rails does its best to set `Content-Type` of response to be sensible.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Maybe this is unrelated, but I'll go ahead and ask. I notice (through tailing test.log and inspecting parameters within the controller) when running my API specs that parameters get parsed differently (numbers stay as numbers, rather than being converted to strings) when I explicitly pass `format: :json` in the request. That gave me the idea that it somehow set the Accept header. Is that not the case?

Comment: @BradRice What request? From a test framework? What parameters then, given in query string or sent as an entity via `POST` and the likes?

Comment: Using RSpec framework, I'm testing the index action of a controller.

`let(:params) { {my_resource_id: my_resource.to_param, format: :json} }`

`subject(:invoke_request) { get :index, params }`

Then merging in other parameters under a context block. When I pass these parameters in under the test, they're integers. If I don't pass the format under params (as I did above), the controller parses them as strings. If I add in the format specifier, they're parsed as integers.

Comment: @BradRice I don't really know, seems like an implementation detail; this might be related: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L597

Comment: That would make a lot of sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the following initializers:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/756baf296b3cb3f7bc40d5843e259276695071ab/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb#L113

This is where how they look up for headers content type to set for.

```
if content_type = self[CONTENT_TYPE]
 type, charset = content_type.split(/;\s*charset=/)
 @content_type = Mime::Type.lookup(type)
 @charset = charset || self.class.default_charset
end
```

so you can even programatically set content_type to header, or params or as a .format